# How to make sure that Fresco will render all images successfully? Android

Tags: android, image, fresco

I have an optimized RecyclerView. Images to the items of this RecyclerView are rendered by Fresco. It works well. But if I scroll RecyclerView too fast, some of items remain empty.
How can I control whether loading was successful, and how to try again if it was failed?

Comment: Do the items remain empty continuously, or do they appear if you stop scrolling? You might simply be scrolling faster than your network can keep up.

Comment: maybe. However now I use Glide library. It works much more faster and any problems occur. Thanks for advices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in their docs, you can add ControllerListener to get the download events:
http://frescolib.org/docs/listening-download-events.html#_

You retry on the `onFailure` or log or do whatever you require.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. But, unfortunately, in my case onFailure event doesn`t occure. only onSubmit, onRelease and onFinalImageSet